# GIT over HTTP configure auth username. credential.username not working?

Tags: git, gitolite, git-config

I am working on a project where the git repo (gitolite) is configured to only allow me https access.  Worse the user name they created for me to authenticate with is dreadful.  In my .git/config I have user.name set to my real name, so that my commits are correctly associated me me.  However, whenever I push or pull, I must remember and correctly type (Hidden none the less!) my dreadful auth user name. I want to set my auth user id in the configuration for my local git repo.

Per http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config and http://git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials.html, I tried

```
git config credential.username <bletcherous-name>
```

and

```
git config credential.https://git-server.myco.com.username <bletcherous-name>
```

but these had no effect. I was still prompted for my user name when ever I connected.

Ultimately I did find that I could do the following.  But it seems like the below is a hack and that the above should have worked.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin https://bletcherous-name@git-server.myco.com/git/my-repo.git
```

Answer (score 1):

In summary:

```
git config --local credential.https://git-server.myco.com.username bletcherous-name
```

Here's a shell transcript showing what this and other similar things do to the Git config file, so you can (as I prefer) just edit the config file directly.

```
localuser@localhost:~$ mkdir foo
localuser@localhost:~$ cd foo
localuser@localhost:~/foo$ git init
Initialized empty Git repository in /home/localuser/foo/.git/
localuser@localhost:~/foo$ cat .git/config
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
localuser@localhost:~/foo$ git remote add origin https://bletcherous-name@git-server.myco.com/git/my-repo.git
localuser@localhost:~/foo$ cat .git/config
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
url = https://bletcherous-name@git-server.myco.com/git/my-repo.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
localuser@localhost:~/foo$ git remote rm origin
localuser@localhost:~/foo$ git remote add origin https://git-server.myco.com/git/my-repo.git
localuser@localhost:~/foo$ cat .git/config
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
url = https://git-server.myco.com/git/my-repo.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
localuser@localhost:~/foo$ git config --local credential.https://git-server.myco.com.username bletcherous-name
localuser@localhost:~/foo$ cat .git/config
[core]
repositoryformatversion = 0
filemode = true
bare = false
logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
url = https://git-server.myco.com/git/my-repo.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[credential "https://git-server.myco.com"]
username = bletcherous-name
localuser@localhost:~/foo$
```